# DBSCAN Clustersize smaller than MinPts

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, parameters, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I just thought about some special cases for DBSCAN. The case is illustrated  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaLV9.jpg).
Assume eps equals to the radius of the circles. For MinPts=3 p and r are corepoints. It is unclear wether q belongs to the cluster of p or of r. If a recursive implementation is used and the algorithm checks r first, q would be part of the cluster of r. Hence p would define a cluster with just two elements. The original [paper](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf) states: "Note that a cluster wrt. Eps and MinPts contains at least MinPts points [...]"
Am I missing something here or was this special case just not considered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In example, q is also a core point: there are three points in the circle: p, q, r. You need minPts=4 in this example.

You need to distinguish the *theoretical* definition of a density cluster from the efficient algorithm output, which only "almost" gives the theoretical result for a good reason: In the theoretical model, q would be part of both clusters. But that is inconvenient and surprising to *users*.

You are not the first to notice. Even Wikipedia knows this:

> While minPts intuitively is the minimum cluster size, in some cases DBSCAN *can* produce smaller clusters.[5] A DBSCAN cluster consists of at least one core point.[5] As other points may be border points to more than one cluster, there is no guarantee that at least minPts points are included in every cluster.

Reference [5] is the article

> Schubert, Erich; Sander, Jörg; Ester, Martin; Kriegel, Hans Peter; Xu, Xiaowei (July 2017). "DBSCAN Revisited, Revisited: Why and How You Should (Still) Use DBSCAN". ACM Trans. Database Syst. 42 (3): 19:1–19:21. doi:10.1145/3068335. ISSN 0362-5915.

Which contains the footnote:

> Note that this can, in rare cases, lead to a cluster with fewer than minPts points, if too many border points are reachable
>   by different clusters, and have previously been assigned to other clusters. Every cluster will at least have one core point.
>   Multi-assignment to exactly represent the theoretical model—or an assignment by shortest distance—can be implemented
>   easily.